# Value of variable into execute statement of function

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I need to fetch the current database and pass it into a query for user creation so that it creates the user in the group using the current database.

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_dbuser(
    v_username NAME,
    v_password TEXT)
RETURNS smallint AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE ROLE "%I" IN GROUP “%I”_group LOGIN 
PASSWORD ''%I''', v_username, current_database(), v_password);
    RETURN 1;
    -- Simple Exception
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
        RETURN 0;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
COST 100;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I am unable to create user using this function, when I call it like -
    SELECT public.create_dbuser(v_username := 'test' ,v_password := 'pw123);
What am I doing wrong here? is create user DDL unsupported here?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Just exception, as it returns 0. not sure how can I catch a a more specific exception. Beginner here, my apologies for not being more helpful.

Comment: If you remove the exception handler you will be able to see the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it to work by removing "" for the _group part.
A follow-up question, with a similar function, I am using the statement -
   EXECUTE FORMAT(‘ALTER ROLE '%I' WITH CONNECTION LIMIT 0’, v_username);
But its giving an error - syntax error at or near 'ROLE', also tried with USER, same error. So unable to create the function, any idea what could be wrong with that?